# How do I get the text after the command in discordpy

Tags: python, discord

How do I get the text after the command in discordpy? for example "!say hello" how do I get the hello?

Comment: Please do a little bit of research before posting on Stack Overflow. Read this for further information :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the argument as a parameter in your command.

```py
@commands.command()
async def say(ctx, *, args):
   await ctx.send(args) #sends entire

#another method
@commands.command()
async def say_first(ctx, args):
   await ctx.send(args) #sends only the first word

#another method
@commands.command()
async def say_list(ctx, *args):
   await ctx.send(args) #sends args as a list
```

Example

```
!say hello there
> hello there
!say_first hello there
> hello
!say_list hello there
> ('hello', 'there')
```

### References:

- [command_arguments](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html?highlight=commands#keyword-only-arguments)
- [commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html?highlight=commands#)